# How can I create a list from a to z, and A to Z

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to create a list from a to z, and from A to Z. Plese help me!

Comment: from `string` module `string.ascii_letters`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. SO is not a code-writing service, and you're expected to do at least a bit of research yourself before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `string` module, with `string.ascii_uppercase` and `string.ascii_lowercase`.

If you type:

```
import string
string.ascii_uppercase
```

You get:

```
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

If you type:

```
string.ascii_lowercase
```

You'll get the same result, but in lowercase.

To solve your problem you can do:

```
import string

upper_case = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
lower_case = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

`upper_case` and `lower_case` will be both lists ranging from a to z.